# WebGL: round line joints via shader in 2D

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I want to render lines of arbitrary thickness in WebGL. From looking around the best way appears to be to generate geometry for a TRIANGLE_STRIP.
My lines are updated in each frame (they're simulated ropes basically) and I am heavily cpu bound already so I want as much work as possible on the gpu and as little work as possible on the cpu.

So from what I understand the least amount of work to do is to push a buffer with each points twice and an index so the vertex shader can push them apart.
I have that working with miter-joints.

But I want round-joints. All things I've found on google however talk about generated extra triangles in the joint-region and pushing them to the cpu. Since WebGL doesn't have geometry shaders there is no obvious way to get that concept onto the gpu.
The fact that vertices are shared between lines in a TRIANGLE_STRIP doesn't make this easier.

My current solution is to make it so that the fragment shader for a fragment that results from a line between A and B has the a varying that interpolates from A to 
B, a varying that interpolates from B to A and can tell where in the interpolation it is. That gives me 2 unknown values and 2 equations. Solving them gives me A and B in the fragment shader. It's more complex to get right than it may sound at first as a TRIANGLE_STRIP reuses vertices and it has small (acceptable to me though) issues with accuracy around the middle and the edges of the interpolation.
It's a pretty convoluted solution.

Is there any "common" solution to rendering round line joints via shaders?
How do big library like three.js handle this? I've tried to search their source, but it's a big project ;)

Comment: at the ends discard fragments that are close to the vertices, (where close does not mean euclidean distance but something that produces inverted circle/hyperbolae ), then add some smoothness etc...

Comment: Somehow using the distance between the line vertices and the fragments is what I am also thinking about, but I've not find a very straightforward way to make it so that each fragment knows which vertices it needs to consider.

Comment: Is this for 2D or 3D?

Comment: editing the title: 2D
Also adding a little info on what I am doing right now to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since implemented a solution I am happy with now.

The key points are:

- use mither joints generated in the vertex shader
- use a bunch of varyings and the point index to alternate between two sets of them to find the segment in the fragment shader

I've written a blog post about the details here: http://nanodesu.info/oldstuff/2D-lines-with-round-joints-using-WebGL-shaders/

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to try: send to the GPU the center vertex position, a polarity (+1, or -1) and the direction of vertex. Eg. [A, +1, dir(B-A)],[A, -1, dir(B-A)], [B, +1, dir(C-B)],...

The cross product of camera viewing direction and the vertex direction multiplied by the polarity + vertex center `(cross(camDir, a_vertexDir) * a_polarity + a_vertexCenter)` gives the geometry of the line. Do this in the vertex shader. Send the interpolated center positions to the fragment shader and use the distance between the fragment and the interpolated center position to modulate the line.

The idea is similiar to this: http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/05/webgl-rendering-of-solid-trails/.

Comment: I must admit I don't fully understand your concept to generate the geometry, though I think I do not need to use my camera direction in 2D. My generation of the geometry in the vertex shader works like this: https://mattdesl.svbtle.com/drawing-lines-is-hard
When I let it interpolate over the line and use the distance of the fragments I get this: https://i.imgur.com/dFvQQui.png which isn't the line it is supposed to be. The interpolated center isn't the closest point on the line to each fragment of the generated triangles I think. At least that's true for my triangle generation.

Comment: While I am still looking for anybody who can share any cool methods of doing this I am somewhat happy now with the solution I have now. +1 to you for pointing me at that blog post, its suggested memory layout cut my buffer size in half :)

Comment: The concept is essentially the same as in the blog you posted to push out the vertices from the center of the line. If interpolation is not good enough then you may want to look into implementing a point-ray distance function in fragment shader. Then if dist(frag_pos, line) > width, discard. (or adjust alpha or similar)

Comment: Okay that is pretty much exactly what I am doing and somehow after reading your answers I think I just realized how I can simplify the math to get the data into the fragment shader. I'll test it out. Maybe I'll make a blog post explaining it in detail later once tested :)